# Animation lag and performance issues on web application that is always running

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

the web app I am developing is rather typical. MySQL to store data, PHP to retrieve, jQuery to make it look nice and AJAX to make it async.

My client only uses FireFox and has the web app potentially open 24/7. The app may request *a lot* of data over several hours and is constantly updating a large table on the page. I have noticed with FireFox that within an hour or so that jquery animations (even the most simple ones) will start to lag. I have confirmed that this is the cause (the long period of time that the browser is open) because starting a fresh new browser will remedy this.

I have read some things about FF garbage collector not being optimal for its JS engine, but I don't really know if this is the issue. I am looking for any general guidance on how to handle this kind of situation.

Thanks

Comment: I know you only care about Firefox, but have you tried reproducing the behavior in another browser? Maybe it is not a Firefox problem. How many rows can your table get to have? Have you tried adding lots of row in one shot and see if the animations lag?

Comment: Firefox is so bad for me, that I needed to implement a setInterval function to limit row generation to 1ms intervals (potential is 100 0 rows, but these rows have lots of data to deal with when being built). In chrome (and IE!) I never had script lagging issues. In FireFox I would get script timeout popup within 10 seconds. Really disappointing.

Comment: If you have that many rows with a lot of data, you will need to come up with some sort of pagination mechanism.

Comment: Unfortunately my requirements maintain that they must all be visible

Comment: Unless your client is going to be looking at the browser in a movie theater screen I doubt he will be able to see all rows at a time. I wasn't thinking about the standard pagination with a "Prev" & "Next" buttons, but more of an "infinite scroll" where you keep the table with 50 rows and as the user scroll you remove from one end and add on the other end the next rows.

Comment: @tdoakiiii If possible , can post `js` `animation` pieces ? Thanks

Comment: i use an old-fashioned meta refresh to keep non-interactive webapps running 99.99% of the time.

Comment: If this is a 24/7, data-driven page, is animation really that important? Since you don't have to worry about browser compatibility, how about rewrite the logic with "plain" JS and remove all animations?

Comment: Without any code, you won't find much help.  You could be unintentionally stacking events.  This could be any number of things, but we don't know without you showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not given any code but I suspect that its the `setInterval` (mentioned in comments) combined 
with the ajax calls that is causing your problem.

If I get it right you are constantly firing async AJAX calls within an interval function (**CASE 1**).
Or you are firing an interval function for each row generated by the ajax call (**CASE 2**).

If its **CASE 1** (AJAX within a setInterval) than don't - You are flooding your page with ajax calls very quickly (use firebug to see the list of calls)... in this case you can use a recursive ajax function that will call it self once its done.

If its **CASE 2** - You mentiones an interval of 1ms and a ratio of 0-100 rows per call (lets assume 50), 
again you are creating a lot of functions and you are putting the system (memory, GC, Cycle handler) into hard work that may cause hanging and lag in your page... in this case consider using a "pool" object 
where your rows will be temporary stored and just one permanent interval function that will grab rows one by one and draw them to the page at the rate you want (don't forget to remove rows from the pool object).

If those cases don't match your approach than please consider showing us your code or the problematic page.

**About the 24/7 and the table growth:**

You should consider a paging mechanism or a page refresh policy because the larger the page is the more memory it requires - You are generating a very quickly growing table and no human can handle, read, understand that amount of data (at a rate of 1ms ~ 1 new row). you should be professional and make a more "user friendly" approach and maybe implement an infinite scroll style for loading new rows or dumping old ones.

Comment: Thanks. I cannot post the code for many reasons (if I was allowed even, there would be so much to look at ). I am using setInterval that does clear itself when it is called and initiates itself when the function is complete. I actually have no stacking AJAX queries. It's smooth on that end. I like the ideas of showing only maybe 50 rows (potential is 1000 not 100) but I really don't know how because each row may have children or parents (think a table of rows that also reflect parent/children relationships, but may come from the AJAX req in any order). I will give it more thought